# V4/V13 support lib : Fragment work, ViewPager does not?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

Testing other components in android support library,

On device classLoader can't find `ViewPager` however it can find other support components `FragmentActivity`, `Fragments` etc . ( using V4 as well as V13, gives same result)

What's special with `ViewPager` ? Does it depends on another support components to work ? (Like `Fragment` needs `FragmentActivity`)

NOTE: I think I'm properly exporting support library as dependency, else `Fragment` would also not have worked.

Comment: Which revision of the support library you have?

Comment: Can't find exact version anywhere, its REV 10 in SDK Manager.

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by `device classLoader`?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.ViewPager in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example-1.apk]

Comment: Did you try to import it manually: `import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;`. It is weird. It is working fine with me!

Comment: The error happens on Inflating a layout containing a ViewPager: `xmlns:v4support="com.android.support.v4.view"` and  `<v4support:ViewPager android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                       />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reference it like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

`<v4support:ViewPager>` is not correct. you need the whole package name in the xml.

Comment: Solved, Its not referenced like fragment, I need to specify qualified name. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

`android.view.ViewPager` is present in Android 3.0 and later. The support library version has a different package: `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`.

Comment: Wrong. ViewPager is found ONLY in the Support Library.